# Escaping blank lines whilst creating a URL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, escaping

I am trying to construct a URL, but unfortunately the job name includes spaces, which are proving problematic.

The job name is used by several other jobs, so I'm unable to change the name.

Currently I have:

`def log = "${JENKINS_URL}job/A Job With Spaces/${appBuild.getNumber()}/consoleText"`

I have tried:

`def log = "${JENKINS_URL}job/\\A Job With Spaces\\/${build.getNumber()}/consoleText"`

But still, when the URL is generated, the hyperlink appears to stop after `A`, where the first space occurs.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `def log = "${JENKINS_URL}job/A+Job+With+Spaces/${appBuild.getNumber()}/consoleText"` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately, that returns a 404 Page Not Found. 

If I replace the `+` with `%20`, that works, but it then makes the String unreadable.

Comment: problem is, spaces in URLs need encoding...  So you have a choice...  Readable but not working...  Or working

Comment: Fortunately, the ${BUILD_URL} environment variable that Jenkins provides handles this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `${BUILD_URL}` handled the escaping of spaces.

Allowing me to use: `def log = ${BUILD_URL}consoleText`